# Blueprism - Java PopUp Window does not return the control back

Tags: java, automation, blueprism

I am automating a java application using blueprism. When I click a button on the application, a popup window comes. Then I have to interact with the buttons on this popup window.

However it seems impossible since, once the button is clicked (using java press action), the control is not returned back to blueprism. It waits forever until the popup window is closed. So I cannot proceed to next stage where I have the interactions with the popup window.

Is there anyway that I can stop blueprism waiting for the popup to close and I can continue automating the pop up window by attaching it separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to continue my automation using spying. I used **Navigate->Focus action to select the button and then used global send keys on "spacebar" to press the button.** That way blueprism does not wait for popup window to return the control back. Alternatively if there are any shortcut keys, you can global send keys for them instead of using "Press" action. Only drawback is when using spying mode, you can't run anything on the screen except for the app being automated.

Answer (score 1):

The actions done with following modes will wait until a return of control from application:

1. some code-stages (for example MS Excel VBO)
2. java-mode
3. sap-mode

If that is causing the problems, then try other modes, for example win32 mode, UImode or Region mode. If you click this button with these actions, then you should use wait stages to control the flow of application.